# ListFragment onListItemClick not firing on first click on returning from back click

Tags: android

Using ListFragment and OnListItemClick.  The implementation is straight out of the ADT templates for tabs with pager.  ListView populates from default adapter and default simple_list_item_1  - so no buttons, checkboxes, etc to capture the click event.

On returning from a detail view, the next click on a listview item causes the item to highlight, but the OnListenItemClick does not fire.  Second click it fires and goes to detail.  On return from detail view this time, it works on first click.  Next time takes two again.  Alternates in that pattern.

R.id.pager is the MainActivity ViewPager from the default layout. Also, I am popping the BackStack in onViewStateRestored().  I just can't figure out why it takes 2 clicks every other time.

Here is the code.  Thanks!

```
public class ContactListFragment extends ListFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View contactsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_list, container, false);

    String jsonData = Contact.readContactsFromAssets(getActivity());
    ArrayList<Contact> contactList = Contact.makeContactList(jsonData);
    ArrayAdapter<Contact> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    contactList);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return contactsView;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Contact myContact = (Contact)l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    ContactDetailFragment detailFragment = new ContactDetailFragment();

    Bundle contactBundle = new Bundle();
    contactBundle.putString("CELL_NUMBER", myContact.getCellNumber());
    detailFragment.setArguments(contactBundle);

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("contact");
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.pager, detailFragment, "contact");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
    fm.popBackStack("contact", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

}

}
```

fragement_contact_list Layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/contact_view" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onListItemClick was firing after all.  Problem is that the listview remains visible.  I can get it to disappear with the following in onListItemClick():

```
l.setVisibility(android.view.View.GONE);
```

However, I am not sure how to to make it reappear in onViewStateRestored().  For now, I'll set a solid background for the fragment.  Ideally, though, I want to toggle the visibility on the ListView so I can inherit the View background.

Comment: ended up just calling a new intent.